# LCD showing garbage sometimes using RPLCD

Tags: pi-3, python, lcd

I am trying to use a 4x20 LCD display with RPLCD module. Its working. But if I run the program ten times every four or five times LCD shows these three garbage values(See below images). Here is my code:

```
from RPLCD.gpio import CharLCD
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

class LCD(object):
    def __init__(self):
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)

        self.lcd = CharLCD(pin_rs = 15, pin_e = 16 \
            , pin_backlight = 18 \
            , pins_data = [21, 22, 23, 24] \
            , numbering_mode = GPIO.BOARD \
            , cols = 20, rows = 4, dotsize = 8 \
            , charmap = 'A02', auto_linebreaks = True \
            , backlight_mode = 'active_high')

        self.lcd.clear()
        self.lcd.cursor_mode = 'hide'
        self.lcd.backlight_enable = True
        self.lcd.write_string("hello, world")

    def close(self):
        self.lcd.close(clear = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    disp = LCD()

    try:
        while True:
            pass

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        disp.close()
```

[image: lcd garbage 1]
[image: lcd garbage 2]
[image: lcd garbage 3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 1.2.1: https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD/pull/91

If you've been experiencing the described issues with garbled text occasionally on initialization/use of the display, try setting the parameter `compat_mode=True`, which allows for better interoperability with slower displays.

```
    self.lcd = CharLCD(pin_rs = 15, pin_e = 16 \
        , pin_backlight = 18 \
        , pins_data = [21, 22, 23, 24] \
        , numbering_mode = GPIO.BOARD \
        , cols = 20, rows = 4, dotsize = 8 \
        , charmap = 'A02', auto_linebreaks = True \
        , backlight_mode = 'active_high' \
        , compat_mode = True)
```

Comment: I am currently not working with hardwares, So I can't verify this myself. But by reading comments in github thread, I am assuming this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/dbrgn/RPLCD/issues/70) of the RPLCD module.

[Adafruit CharLCD](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_CharLCD) can be used as an alternative.